# Display products on home page, with "promotion" attribute set to "yes" - not working

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, product-list, dropdown-attribute

I am trying to display a list of products on the home page. The list of products is the products with the attribute "promotion" with the dropdown value "yes". 
So far I have tried the following But it just blank and not actually displaying anything.:

**I have re-used code from my template bought from Template Monster, the code was used to display the "New Products"**

---

Edit 1: Partial Solution found.

Solution:  On the 5th Line in `promotion.phtml` file, change 
`$this->getProductCollection()` to `$this->_getProductCollection()` . This solves the issue and starts displaying.

**But, ideally I have not seen this thing causing issue**

---

---

**Current Code and Approach to solve this issue is as Below**

---

1. Created a Custom file in the Template called `promotion.phtml` in the folder `app/design/frontend/default/template_name/template/catalog/product/`.

Code of the file is as follows:

```
    <?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    ?>

    <?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
        <div class="page-title category-title">
            <h1><?php echo $this->__('Promotional Products') ?></h1>
        </div>
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
            <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
                <ul class="products-grid row" id="new-carousel">
            <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/product">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(228) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"/></a>
                <div class="product-shop">
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
                    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" itemprop="name">
                            <?php $product_name_carousel = strip_tags($_product->getName());
                            if (strlen($product_name_carousel) < 25) echo($product_name_carousel);
                            else { echo mb_substr($product_name_carousel, 0, 25,'UTF-8').'...';} ?>
                        </a></h3>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <div class="desc_grid" itemprop="description"><?php $small_getDescription = strip_tags($_product->getShortDescription());
                            if (strlen($small_getDescription) < 60) echo($small_getDescription);
                            else { echo mb_substr($small_getDescription, 0, 60,'UTF-8').'...';} ?></div>
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                            <span class="btn-separator"></span>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Details') ?>" class="button btn-details" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <!-- <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if ($_compareUrl = $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
                <div class="label-product">
                    <?php if($_product->getData('new')){echo '<span class="new">'.$this->__('New').'</span>';  }?>
                    <?php if($_product->getData('sale')){echo '<span class="sale">'.$this->__('Sale').'</span>';  }?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
                </ul>
                <div class="new-carousel-button">
                    <span class="carousel-pagination"></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery('#new-carousel').carouFredSel({
                    responsive: true,
                    width: '100%',
                    /* prev: '.carousel-prev',
                     next: '.carousel-next', */
                    scroll: 1,
                    auto : {
                        play : 1,
                        timeoutDuration :13000
                    },
                    items: {
                        visible: {
                            min: 1,
                            max: 5
                        },
                        width:234,
                        height:  'variable' //400
                    },
                    mousewheel: true,
                    swipe: {
                        onMouse: false,
                        onTouch: true
                    },
                    pagination: {
                        container: ".carousel-pagination",
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

2. Added the following XML to the XML layout of the Home Page.

   ```
   <reference name="content">
       <block type="core/template" template="catalog/msrp/popup.phtml" name="product.tooltip"></block>
       <block type="catalog/product_list_promotion" name="home.catalog.product.promotion" alias="product_promotion" after="cms.wrapper" template="catalog/product/promotion.phtml">
           <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>30</columns></action>
           <action method="setProductsCount"><count>30</count></action>
           <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
           <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
           <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
       </block>
   </reference>
   ```
3. The content of the File `Promotion.php` in the folder `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List` is as Follows:

   ```
   <?php

   class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Promotion extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
   {
       protected function _getProductCollection()
       {
           if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
               $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
               Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
   // your custom filter
               $collection->addAttributeToFilter('promotion', 1)
                   ->addStoreFilter();

               $this->_productCollection = $collection;
           }
           return $this->_productCollection;
       }
   }
   ```

Any pointers will be much appreciated. I am not a Magento Developer so working my way thru.

Many Thanks in Advance for your time.

Comment: what if in your `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Promotion` you log the collection sql `Mage::log((string) $collection->getSelect())` after you add all your filters.

Comment: @DavidManners thanks for the quick response. I would really appreciate if you can give a bit detailed info. Sorry, but quite a N00b to magento.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the `_getProductCollection` method with this

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/collection')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('promotion', 1)
            ->addStoreFilter();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite()
        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Also, if you have the flat catalog enabled, make sure the attribute `promotion` is marked as "Use in product listing". If it wasn't, then rebuild the indexes after setting it like that.

Comment: And then remove the line `<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>` which is reloading every product again. This is slow and unnecessary with a properly configured collection (hint: your Template Monster theme is not a good one)